# passing custom classes to a webc component/layout in eleventy

Tags: javascript, eleventy

When building a site in eleventy I prefer to reserve the option to pass a custom class into the layout via custom front matter. I'm trying to figure out how to do this in the eleventy + webc ecosystem.

Usually I do something like this in the nunjucks layout:

```
<body class="{{ class }}">
```

And then just do this in the post or page front matter:

```
---    
class: "home"
---
```

I'm sure there's a pretty simple way of doing this for a webc world (where your layouts are also webc files) I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a dynamic variable by prefixing it with a colon (`:`):

```
---
class: "home:
---

<body :class="class">
```

Read more at the official documentation: https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/webc/#dynamic-attributes-and-properties

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a answer? I've just run into this problem trying to switch to using Webc

Only found a temp hacky solution, change my layout to back to base.njk and use

`{% renderTemplate "webc" %} <my-component></my-component> {% endrenderTemplate %}`

Frontmatter then gets passed as normal, Not really a way forward though

Comment: Haven't yet, unfortunately.